# MySQL quotes around values and -100 values return no results

Tags: mysql

I am having two very odd problems.

1) In order for my query to work, at least one of the inputs has to be in quotations.  Not both, but at least one.

2) I can query up to negative 99 or 99.99999999... but as soon as the value is -100, i get no results.

Working querys:

```
 SELECT * FROM findCities WHERE lon >= '-84' AND lon <= '-99.888888'
 SELECT * FROM findCities WHERE lon >= -84 AND lon <= '-99.888888'
```

No results returned:

```
SELECT * FROM findCities WHERE lon >= -84 AND lon <= -99.888888
SELECT * FROM findCities WHERE lon >= '-84' AND lon <= '-100'
```

Table Structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE `findCities` (
 `city_id` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `state_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
 `zip` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `text` text,
 `lat` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `lon` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `cityTempID` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 = default',
 `clinicID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3801 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Seems impossible that it matters, but I am using SQLPro to run the queries.

Comment: You probably do not want latitude and longitude to be `varchar`.  `decimal` makes the most sense to me.

Comment: your lat/lon are strings. you're trying to use strings as numbers. That's NOT going to work properly. `'99' < '101'` is FALSE in strings, because `9` is greater than `1`.

Comment: how woud SELECT * FROM findCities WHERE lon >= -84 AND lon <= -99.888888 ever return anything

Comment: Yea, I noticed that too, and it seems weird but it worked for years (didn't build this script, just inherited it)

Comment: jam em into numeric types

Comment: Okay, so a combination of decimal and changing to query to SELECT * FROM findCities WHERE lon <= -84 AND lon >= -100  works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lon` column is defined as VARCHAR, so the inequality comparison are being done as strings, character by character.

It looks like you want to *numeric* evaluation. It would be much better if your `lon` value was stored as a numeric type. (We use `DECIMAL(10,6)` datatype for our latitude and longitude columns.)

Given what you have, to get this to "work" without an table changes, cast/convert the `lon` column to numeric.

The quickest/easiest way to do that is to add zero to the VARCHAR column, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM findCities WHERE lon+0 <= -84 AND lon+0 >= -99.888888
                                  ^^               ^^
```

Also, your inequality comparisons are reversed, the evaluation `lon >= -84 AND lon <= -99` will never be true for any value of `lon`. You either need to swap the values around, or swap the direction of the inequality comparisons.

To make the conversion more explicit:

```
SELECT *
 FROM findCities 
 WHERE CONVERT(lon,DECIMAL(10,6) <= -84 
   AND CONVERT(lon,DECIMAL(10,6) >= -99.888888
```

If you know that the values you are supplying as literals aren't NULL, but don't know which is the smallest or largest, you can use the `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions...

```
SELECT *
 FROM findCities 
 WHERE CONVERT(lon,DECIMAL(10,6) <= GREATEST( -84.000000, -99.88888 ) 
   AND CONVERT(lon,DECIMAL(10,6) >= LEAST(    -84.000000, -99.888888 )
```

Note that MySQL can't make effective use of a range scan operation on the `lon` column, because of the conversion. The expressions on the left side have to be evaluated for every row in the table. For better performance, make the `lon` column numeric, and reference the bare column.

Comment: Very thorough, thank you.  I have a testing environment, so I tried to update the col type as decimal with no problems regarding data loss, so I will just go with that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't use decimal fields for lon and lat fields cause it's latitude and attitude

anyway you must use **cast** procedure in **where** clause

```
cast(lon as decimal(10,6))
```

see in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8dad/9)